# How to pass unknown URL value from browser adress to javascript source url?

Tags: javascript, url, variables

**The setting:**
Up until now I have been able to successfully pass a couple of known GET variables through my javascript src, such that the client javascript tag will work on any web page, from any domain, like so:

```
<script id="gbScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/myremoteapp/scripts/gb.js?clientid=50&domain=someclientdomain.com"></script>
```

But, now I have need to add one more variable to the source url, and I need to get it from the url that's in the client's browser.

For example, I need to grab the value of "p" from this web page address:
    http://www.yourwebsite.com/?p=2

...and then add it to the url variable string in my client script, like so:

```
<script id="gbScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/myremoteapp/scripts/gb.js?clientid=50&domain=someclientdomain.com&p=2"></script>
```

**LIMITATIONS:**
I can't use server-side code. That's because I have no idea whether the client will add this script to their php page, aspx page, or plain old html page.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**
I tried two back-to-back scripts, the first to create a variable, and then tried to pass that variable in the second script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var url = escape(window.location);</script>
<script id="gbScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/myremoteapp/scripts/gb.js?clientid=50&domain=someclientdomain.com&p="+url+></script>
```

Unfortunately, the src part of the script tag does not seem to honor or recognize a javascript variable. Also, on the remote or hosted page that the script uses, which **is** php, it does not see the client's url at all, much less the url variables of the client address.

**SOLVED:**
In the remote gb.js script code, I just added:

```
var clientLocation = window.location;
```

That gives me the entire url, which I can parse however I need to.

Comment: You might want to try `var url = encodeURI(window.location);` instead. Also, should `&p` at the end of the `<script>`”s `src` attribute be `&p=`?

Comment: Hi Paul, you are right on the "p=". as to encodeURI() vs escape(), yes, that is a better suggestion, but the variable/value still does not show up in the second script. I'm now going to try the solution offered below, by php_nub_qq.

Comment: You can dynamically create the `<script>` tag in any javascript block and add the created tag to the document's head.  Basically, something like `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += "<script id='gbScript' type='text/javascript' etc>"`

Comment: Hi Scott, I do that now. I'm going to post the very simple answer (duh) which came to me as I read the suggestions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks everybody. Even though script is remotely hosted, I see that I can do a:

```
var clientLocation = window.location;

alert(clientLocation);
```

...Add that to my gb.js script, and the correct address of the client's browser displays:

"http://www.yourwebsite.com/?p=2"

Therefore, I don't have to modify my client script.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `window.URL` and perform some regex to get the parameters. A nice function I have found:

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Then you can add the whole script tag from within javascript like so

```
<script>
var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
var oScript= document.createElement("script");
oScript.type = "text/javascript";
oScript.src="other.js";
oHead.appendChild( oScript);
</script>
```

Where you can add your variables in the `oScript.src`

[Source](http://rockmanx.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/get-url-parameters-using-javascript/)
[Source2](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html)

Comment: Going to try this now...Ok, I love SO, not so much because the answers are always exactly right, but because when I try your answers, it leads me to THE answer, which yours did. I will post that answer. Thanks for the brain jog, php_nub_qq!

Comment: If the only parameter you need to get is `p` you don't really need to perform all of this regex, you can build a much simpler one to get just the `p`.

Comment: Yeah, my answer was stupidly simple. Just do a window.location within the script code, itself, and it gives the complete url of the client page. I didn't know a remote script would do that, but it's always the very last thing you try...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for handling GET parameters:

```
  get_query_values: () ->
    vars = {}
    if window.location.href.indexOf('?') <= 0
      return vars
    hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')
    for i in [0..hashes.length - 1]
      hash = hashes[i].split('=')
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1]

    return vars
```

It's in coffeescript, but you see what's going on :)

When calling `query_values = get_query_values()`, you'll get an object.
To use the object in a URL, use like this: `decodeURIComponent($.param(query_values))`.